# Closing Bracket Errors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create stencil letters using CSS. The text editor I am using is notepad++. The issue I'm experiencing is when I type my code in in notepad++ the editor does not recognize the appropiate closing bracket. Please see the code below.

The close tag for S class is supposed to close at the bottom of the page but instead it is closing after the first closing bracket.

```
  .S { //open tag for class S
     margin-left: 80px;
     margin-right: 40px;
     margin-top: 25px; // Optically lower S  
     width: calc(var(--width-1) * 1.1);
     height: 100px;
     display: block;
     transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(4deg);
     border-radius: 4em 0;
     background-color: var(--color);
     position: relative;

  &::before,
  &::after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
  } //S is closing here instead and not recognizing the closing bracket at the end of the page

  &::before {
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     transform: translate(72px, 1px) skew(14deg) rotate(200deg);
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 35px solid transparent;
     border-right: 35px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 35px solid var(--color);
     border-radius: 50%;
  }

  &::after {
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     transform: translate(-72px, -8px) rotate(-150deg) skew(0deg);
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 40px solid transparent;
     border-right: 40px solid transparent;
     border-top: 25px solid var(--color);
     border-radius: 50%;
  }
} //Close tag for class S
```

Comment: then move it .. ?

Comment: I assume the above code is the corrected version, as it looks right to me (if it is SASS/SCSS)

Comment: Your code is SASS.  Might need a plugin for Notepad+.  Like: https://github.com/marvinlabs/notepad-plus-plus-scss-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand is a feature of Sass. Are you using that or is this supposed to be standard CSS?

https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/